# KeyError: 'Host' - How to access JSON body from URL in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-3.8

How can I retrieve JSON data sent to AWS lambda function? I need to pass the data sent to AWS lambda to one of the function in the code. But I'm getting KEY Error. Any suggestion on how to resolve it?

In the cloud watch I see that the data is shown as:

`"body": "{ \"Host\": \"Zabbix server\", \"Key\": \"lambda.test\", \"Value\": \"5.96\" }",`

I'm getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'Host'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/AlertMetricSender.py", line 14, in lambda_handler
    Host = event['Host']
```

I'm sending the request as follows:

```
curl -X POST 'https://myapi.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/default/zabbixPy'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "Host": "Zabbix server", "Key": "lambda.test", "Value": "5.98" }'
```

`AlertMetricSender.py:`

```
from modules.ZabbixSender import ZabbixSender
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

  Host = event['Host']
  Key = event['Key'] 
  Value = event['Value']

  sender = ZabbixSender("10.10.10.10", 10051)
  sender.add(Host, Key, Value)
  sender.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the 'body'. Try the below

```
Host = event['body']['Host']
```